# sql - How to have multiple select/from statements in one query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to pull a report where each column is selecting from a specific table set. However, one of the columns needs to pull from a completely different table set and still be included in the same report. Of course, this doesn't work:

```
select u.first_name, ticket_work.time_spent
FROM tickets LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_work ON ticket_work.ticket_id = tickets.id JOIN users u
(select count(tickets.id) FROM tickets JOIN users u)

where tickets.assigned_to = u.id
```

...

So just the part `(select count(tickets.id) FROM tickets JOIN users u)` needs to be selecting from the different table set but still be included in the report.

Comment: can you share table information & sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question.  Are you wanting to return the user, the count of tickets for that user, and the amount of time spent overall?  If so, something like this should work:

```
select u.id, u.first_name, 
    SUM(tw.time_spent) summed_time_spent, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) count_tickets
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN tickets t
        ON u.id = t.assigned_to
    LEFT JOIN ticket_work tw
        ON tw.ticket_id = t.id 
GROUP BY u.id, u.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is unclear, but just generally, it sounds like you're trying to join to a `derived table` (i.e., a query).  In that case, do this:

```
SELECT...
FROM...
table_A A LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT keyfield, valuefield FROM table_b WHERE ...) B 
   ON A.keyfield = B.keyfield
```

Does that make sense?  To make a derived table, you put a query inside of parenthesis, give it an alias ('B' in this case), and then join it to your other tables as though it were a regular table.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about your table structure but you may use a sub query for such requirement

```
select u.first_name, ticket_work.time_spent,(select count(tickets.id) FROM tickets where ticket.id=ticket_work.ticket_id) as myCount
FROM tickets LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_work ON ticket_work.ticket_id = tickets.id JOIN users u
where tickets.assigned_to = u.id
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to run a "sub query" but incorporate it into the main query with the associated user (u.first_name). I tried doing it this way and it compiled but did not provide the correct result. It didn't associate the count with the user (u.first_name) column. It just gave an overall count for all users.

Comment: @user2232524 I'd be able to help better if you share table structure & some sample data.